# 公開したアプリでgoogle-api-services-sheets:v4が繋がらない

Tags: android, api

私の制作しているアプリで「google-api-services-sheets:v4」を使用しています。
　AndroidStudioで直接、Android端末に出力した場合、問題無く繋がりシートの全データを取得できます。
　しかし、google playで公開すると「The following error occurred:null」と表示され繋がりません。
　この問題の解決策についてなにか心当たりはございませんでしょうか？
　アドバイスを宜しくお願い致します。

これまで調べたところ、
　v3は公開用のキーの取得が必要と有りましたが、v4では表記が見つかりませんでした。
　手がかりだけでもいただけますと幸いです。

「追記情報」
・開発は　Java　で行っております。
・APは　Android のクライアント ID　で登録しています。
　　ここで「パッケージ名と SHA-1 署名証明書フィンガープリント」を登録しました。

・「GoogleAPIConsoleに登録しているkeystore証明書はGooglePlayStoreへ申請時のものが登録されていますか？
　　「keystore証明書」の申請がわかりません。
　　　実装時（今年３月）に四苦八苦して動作させたため、記憶がおぼろげな状態です。
　　　この作業の詳細について詳しく説明をいただけませんか？

・実装作業で参照したHP
　https://qiita.com/InoueDaiki/items/77e5798a4933a2531c13

以上となります。
宜しくお願い致します。

「作業内容　2019/08/04」

・「apkに署名」から以下を参照して設定。
　「Androidの署名について（releaseバリアントでビルドする）」
　　　https://qiita.com/takehilo/items/7c02a4eba177ac76dcc4

※なお、「releaseバリアントの署名設定」は設定しておりませんでした。
　　　恥ずかしい話ですがこのような設定が必要であることも知りませんでした。

・「Signing Configs」に「release2019」を作成。
　　　各情報を入力。
・「Default Config」の「Signing Configs」を設定。

・以下を参照にSHA-1を確認。
　　https://qiita.com/Dreamwalker/items/5888bfac4bfa65d3d68e

ここでログに表示された内容を見ると、
　　　　Variant: release
　　　　Config: release2019
　　　に「リリース用SHA-1」を確認しました。

・念の為、GoogleAPIConsoleで「リリース用SHA-1」を使用した「認証情報」を作成しました。

まとめると、自分の理解では以下の設定が抜けていたことを確認できました。
　　未設定の「releaseバリアントの署名設定」を設定。
　　GoogleAPIConsoleで「リリース用SHA-1」を使用した「認証情報」を作成。

ただし、結果として公開アプリでは繋がりませんでした。
　
　上記内容や他に抜けている部分があればご指摘いただければ幸いです。

[image: release2019の内容]
[image: SHA-1のログの内容]

「作業内容　2019/08/04　追記」
　
　Sieg 様がご指摘いただいた内容となっております。
　※OAuth 2.0 クライアント IDで作成していますので少し違いますが、
　　「リリース情報の未登録」が原因なので同じと判断しております。
　同じ問題に悩んだ人に向けてできるだけ情報を記載します。

・「Google Play Console」
　　①「アプリの証明」の
　　②「アプリへの署名証明書　SHA-1 証明書のフィンガープリント」を確認します。
　
　・「Google API Console 」
　　③「アプリへの署名証明書　SHA-1 証明書のフィンガープリント」で認証情報を作成します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 環境や構築された手順の概要などがないので、思いついた疑問を並べてみます。開発はJavaですか？Kotlinですか？APIはどのように登録しましたか？GoogleAPIConsoleに登録しているkeystore証明書はGooglePlayStoreへ申請時のものが登録されていますか？

Comment: Sieg 様

ご返信いただきありがとうございます。
どのように質問して良いのかもわからない状態だったのでご指摘大変助かります。
ご指摘に沿って内容に追記させていただきます。

Comment: 参考リンクでいうとパッケージ名とフィンガープリントを登録する部分ですね。フィンガープリントはkeystore証明書から出したと思います。そしてこのkeystoreはapkをビルドし署名するためにも使っていると思います。ここら辺の手順を思い出せますか？またAPIConsoleはGoogleアカウントがあれば再確認出来るものなので今登録されているパッケージ名とフィンガープリントがPlaystoreに申請したapkに署名したものと同一か確認してみては？

Comment: Sieg 様 ご返信が遅くなり申し訳ございません。
ご指摘頂いた内容の検証をしておりました。
残念ながら、まだ、動作しておりません。
今までの作業内容を追加させていただきます。
もし、何かアドバイスをあれば宜しくお願い致します。
他の方々も引き続き宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `「GoogleAPIConsoleで「リリース用SHA-1」を使用した「認証情報」を作成しました。」`：新しく認証情報を作成したとのことですが、今使っている認証情報とは別に作ったということですよね？多分ビルドしなおしかと思いますがその後時間が経過して動作しましたでしょうか？元々使っていた認証情報に「パッケージ名と SHA-1 署名証明書フィンガープリント」の「項目を追加」からReleaseのフィンガープリントを登録しては？また、認証情報の`API の制限`の欄も確認してください。取得データがnullということで「APIに許可がない」などの権限が理由で取得できていない可能性が高いかと思います。

Comment: Sieg 様 
詳細なご説明をいただきありがとうございます。

諸事情でご報告が遅くなり申し訳ございません。
現在、問題が解決いたしました。
先に更新日の後、再度、設定情報を調査しSieg 様 がご説明頂いた回答に
たどり着きました。
ご指摘のとおりに数分で動作を確認できました。
確認に開発用Android端末だけでなく、他のAndroid端末でも行っていたため
報告が遅くなってしまいました。
Sieg 様 の貴重なお時間を使ってしまい申し訳ございません。

本当に感謝しております。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

追記されている最後の画像がズバリなのですが、Releaseのフィンガープリントが、
[Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) に登録されておりますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
コメントでは画像が添付できないので、ついでに回答しますが、
参考にしているリンクの[「パッケージ名とフィンガープリントを登録する」](https://qiita.com/InoueDaiki/items/77e5798a4933a2531c13#%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E5%90%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%83%95%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) で登録しているはずです。
ですが、ここで登録したのは恐らくDebugのものであり、Releaseのものではないので、許可されていないのではないでしょうか？

ここに新しくReleaseのものを登録すれば早くて5分～10分程度で動作するようになるかと思います。（長いとそれ以上かと思いますが一日以上はかからないかと）